# Any examples for use Flashpunk TiledSpritemap?

Tags: actionscript-3, frameworks, sprite

Flashpunk framework have "Spritemap.as" Class which apply bitmap Spritesheet to a Entity, but also, framework include "TiledSpritemap.as"

Question is - can I use this to apply single spritesheet file, with different animations, for a entity?

Objective is - use one enemy class, with different sprites (in one spritesheet)

If this possible, second question is how to set X & Y offset, if sprites have different sizes

see example tiledspritemap here (it's from VVVVVV)
http://i.piccy.info/i7/12c5057ece64edccbf40af5902a6839d/4-57-1421/62678728/sprites.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TiledSpritemap

TiledSpritemap is used to make single animated sprite tile (for example, 32x32px) be tiled across X or Y (or both of them). For example, if you have lava spritesheet, that contains 7 sprites of boiling lava and you'd like to create pool of lava, you may use this class. Example of use:

```
// embed a resource somewhere in your class 
[Embed(source = "../../assets/lava.png")]
private var lavaGfx:Class;

public function AnimatedEntity () 
{
  var spriteWidth:uint=32;
  var spriteHeight:uint=32;
  var objectWidth:uint=100; // pool of lava, that has 100px width
  var objectHeight:uint=32;

  var t = new TiledSpritemap(this.lavaGfx, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, objectWidth, objectHeight );
  t.add("boil", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4, true);
  graphic = hb;
  t.play("boil");           
}
```

where, instead of *spriteWidth* and *spriteHeight* you should use width and height of a single sprite in your spritesheet (32x32, for instance), instead of *objectWidth* and *objectHeight* - desired width and height of your object. Function *t.add* has the following attributes: name of the animation, that would be used, when you call "play"; array of frame indices to animate through; frameRate of the animation; boolean, that set whether the animation should loop.

### Spritemap

Spritemap can be used for making bunch of different animations from one spritesheet, using code, similar to the code mentioned above:

```
public function AnimatedEntity () 
{
  var spriteWidth:uint= 32;
  var spriteHeight:uint= 32;

  var t = new Spritemap(enemyGfx, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);

  t.add("run", [0, 1, 2], 10, true);
  t.add("jumpUp", [3, 4], 9, true);
  t.add("jumpDown", [5, 6], 9, true);
  t.add("attack", [7, 8, 9], 10, true);
  t.add("standIdle", [10, 11, 12], 10, true);
}
```

At the moment, FlashPunk out of the box is not able to use spritesheets (or Atlases, as it was called in other 2d game engines) that made of sprites with different sizes.

Comment: Cool! Many thanks, now I clearly understand TiledSpritemap functionality and "Atlases" in FlashPunk too.

Спасибо :)